# Using monero-php, I am getting "Method not found" when calling open_wallet

Tags: daemon, rpc, wallet, php

I want to open my Monero testnet wallet via a php script 
using a remote node but it's returning: "Method not found".

Here is the code I am using:

```
$hostname = 'node.xmr.to';
$port     = '28081';
$daemonRPC          = new \MoneroIntegrations\MoneroPhp\daemonRPC($hostname, $port);
$getblockcount      = $daemonRPC->getblockcount();
$on_getblockhash    = $daemonRPC->on_getblockhash(42069);
$getlastblockheader = $daemonRPC->getlastblockheader();
$get_info           = $daemonRPC->get_info();

$walletRPC     = new \MoneroIntegrations\MoneroPhp\walletRPC($hostname, $port);
$open_wallet   = $walletRPC->open_wallet('<wallet name>','<wallet password>');
dd($open_wallet);
die();
```

Also I am trying to get unique deposit address for my Monero wallet.

Answer (score 1):

The wallet RPC and daemon RPC are *different*. Refer to the projects [documentation](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp#getting-started) on how to run both wallet and daemon RPCs.

The node you reference at `node.xmr.to` is a *daemon* RPC, not a wallet RPC, therefore you cannot use it for any of the wallet commands, only daemon commands.

To use a wallet RPC (like you are trying to do from php), you have to run this wallet RPC yourself (e.g. the app `monero-wallet-rpc`, again mentioned in the [monerophp documentation](https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp#getting-started)). Note, the wallet RPC still needs to connect to a daemon (`monerod`), for which you can specify a remote daemon if you are not running your own local full node.

For the wallet RPC to use a remote daemon, you launch passing the parameter `--daemon-address`. E.g.

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --help
...
--daemon-address arg                  Use daemon instance at <host>:<port>
...
```